# How do I reorder variables on the X-axis in ggplot boxplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Screenshot]

I want the order to be 0H Control, 1% A.S, 5%A.S, 10% A.S, 1% FCS, 5% A.S, 10% FCS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your factors before plotting.

```
dt$Condition <- factor(dt$Condition, levels = c("0H Control"....))
```